# Correct testing pattern in Project Reactor block() vs StepVerifier

Tags: unit-testing, testing, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Recently I noticed that my team follows two approaches on how to write tests in Reactor. First one is with help of [`.block()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--) method. And it looks something like that:

```java
@Test
void set_entity_version() {
    Entity entity = entityRepo.findById(ID)
                              .block();
    assertNotNull(entity);
    assertFalse(entity.isV2());

    entityService.setV2(ID)
                 .block();

    Entity entity = entityRepo.findById(ID)
                              .block();

    assertNotNull(entity);
    assertTrue(entity.isV2());
}
```

And the second one is about using of [`StepVerifier`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.html). And it looks something like that:

```java
@Test
void set_entity_version() {

    StepVerifier.create(entityRepo.findById(ID))
                .assertNext(entity -> {
                    assertNotNull(entity);
                    assertFalse(entity.isV2());
                })
                .verifyComplete();
            
    StepVerifier.create(entityService.setV2(ID)
                                     .then(entityRepo.findById(ID)))
                .assertNext(entity -> {
                    assertNotNull(entity);
                    assertTrue(entity.isV2());
                })
                .verifyComplete();
}
```

In my humble opinion, the second approach looks more *reactive* I would say. Moreover, official docs are very clear on that:

> A StepVerifier provides a declarative way of creating a verifiable script for an async Publisher sequence, by expressing expectations about the events that will happen upon subscription.

Still, I'm really curious, what way should be encouraged to use as the main road for doing testing in Reactor. Should `.block()` method be abandoned completly or it could be useful in some cases? If yes, what such cases are?

Thanks!

Comment: `StepVerifier` allows you to verify individual events in the chain, whereas `block()` would only ever allow you to verify the outcome at the end. I can't think of any reason to ever use `block()` over `StepVerifier` but can think of plenty not to.

Comment: In case of Mono I don't really see any advantage of StepVerifier.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Tons of advantages. You can verify whether it has subscribes/errors/completes/onNext events. You can verify an event occurs within a time limit. Verify if elements have been correctly discarded via a filter. Verify various aspects of the subscriberContext + lots more. Block() literally just gives you an imperative value at the end. Gives no way of testing what has actually happened within the chain.

Comment: These are quite useful for a Flux, not so much for a Mono. Most of the cases, I don't need such low-level asserts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from https://medium.com/swlh/stepverifier-vs-block-in-reactor-ca754b12846b

> There are pros and cons of both `block()` and `StepVerifier` testing
> patterns. Hence, it is necessary to define a pattern or set of rules
> which can guide us on how to use StepVerifier and block().
>
> In order to decide which patterns to use, we can try to answer the
> following questions which will provide a clear expectation from the
> tests we are going to write:
>
> - Are we trying to test the reactive aspect of the code or just the output of the code?
> - In which of the patterns we find clarity based on the 3 A’s of testing i.e Arrange, Act, and Assert, in order to make the test
>   understandable?
> - What are the limitations of the block() API over StepVerifier in testing reactive code? Which API is more fluent for writing tests in
>   case of `Exception`?
>
> If you try answering all these questions above, you will find the
> answers to “what” and “where”. So, just give it a thought before
> reading the following answers:
>
> - block() tests the output of the code and not the reactive aspect. In    such a case where we are concerned about testing the output of
>   the code, rather than the reactive aspect of the code we can use a
>   block() instead of StepVerifier as it is easy to write and the tests
>   are more readable.
> - The assertion library for a block() pattern is better organised in terms of `3 A’s pattern` i.e `Arrange`, `Act`, and `Assert` than
>   StepVerifier. In StepVerfier while testing a method call for a mock
>   class or even while testing a Mono output one has to write expectation
>   in the form of chained methods, unlike assert which in my  opinion
>   decreases the readability of the tests. Also, if you forget to write
>   the terminal step i.e `verify()` in case of StepVerifier, the   code
>   will not get executed and the test will go green. So, the developer
>   has to be very careful about calling verify at end of the chain.
> - There are some aspects of reactive code that can not be tested by using block() API. In such cases, one should use StepVerifier when we
>   are testing a `Flux` of data or subscription delays or subscriptions
>   on different `Schedulers`, etc, where the developer is bound to use
>   StepVerifier.
> - To verify exception by using block() API you need to use `assertThatThrownBy`  API in assertions library that catches the
>   exception. With the use of an assertion API, error message and
>   instance of the exception can be asserted. StepVerifier also provides
>   assertions on exception by `expectError()` API and supports the
>   assertion of the element before errors are thrown in a Flux of
>   elements that can not be achieved by block(). So, for the assertion of
>   exception, StepVerifier is better than a block() as it can assert
>   both `Mono/Flux`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [StepVerifier](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_testing_a_scenario_with_stepverifier). It allows more options:

- Verify that you expect n element in a flux
- Verify that the flux/mono complete
- Verify that an error is expected
- Verify that a sequence is expected n element followed by an error (impossible to test with .block())

From the official doc:

```java
public <T> Flux<T> appendBoomError(Flux<T> source) {
  return source.concatWith(Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("boom")));
}

@Test
public void testAppendBoomError() {
  Flux<String> source = Flux.just("thing1", "thing2"); 

  StepVerifier.create( 
    appendBoomError(source)) 
    .expectNext("thing1") 
    .expectNext("thing2")
    .expectErrorMessage("boom") 
    .verify(); 
}
```

- Create [initial context](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_testing_the_context)
- [Using virtual time to manipulate time](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_manipulating_time). So when you have something like Mono.delay(Duration.ofDays(1)) you don't have to wait 1 day for your test to complete.
- Expect that no event are emitted for a given duration...