# java springboot reactive assertNotNull doesn't work in Mono.doOnNext

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to do unit test case here is my function..

```java
    @SpringBootTest
    public class ABCTests{

    @Autowired
    private VDao vDao;
    
    @Test
    public void addDummyVan() {
        Mono<Van> vmono = Mono.just(createDummyVan());
        vDao.addVan(vmono).doOnNext(v-> assertNotNull(v.getId()));
      }
    }
```

To test this. In `vDao.addVan` function, I'm returning `Mono<Van>` where in van object keeping id value as null intentionally. But test case is still not failing.

Comment: What result are you getting? And what is your question please be specific

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `doOnNext` operator is used for side effects, and it doesn't affect the test assertion. The `assertNotNull` call is not part of the reactive flow, so it doesn't get executed during the execution of the reactive stream.

To properly test the behavior of your `addVan` method, you should use a testing framework designed for reactive code, such as Project Reactor's `StepVerifier`. Here's how you can modify your test to use `StepVerifier`:

```java
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

@SpringBootTest
public class ABCTests {

    @Autowired
    private VDao vDao;

    @Test
    public void addDummyVan() {
        Mono<Van> vmono = Mono.just(createDummyVan());
        
        StepVerifier.create(vDao.addVan(vmono))
            .expectNextMatches(v -> v.getId() != null)
            .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

In this modified test:

1. We use `StepVerifier.create` to create a verifier for the reactive stream returned by `vDao.addVan(vmono)`.
2. We use `expectNextMatches` to expect that the next element emitted by the stream (`v`) satisfies the condition that `v.getId()` is not null.
3. We use `verifyComplete` to ensure that the stream completes successfully after emitting the expected element.

With this approach, the test will fail if the `addVan` method doesn't properly set the `id` field in the `Van` object before emitting it in the reactive stream. This allows you to test the behavior of your reactive code accurately.

Comment: Thank you @Jeet! sorry but I recently started with reactive. How to gain more knowledge or understanding on your comment "The assertNotNull call is not part of the reactive flow". How we something like this will not work in reactive or in other words what will work in such flow vs what will not work. Where to gain such a knowledge?

Comment: Found this stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62697139/correct-testing-pattern-in-project-reactor-block-vs-stepverifier This gave some details but I'm looking to understand fundamentals. Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: I tried the suggestions but it is still failing with below:

java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNextMatches" failed (expected: onNext(); actual: onError(org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: Write operation error on server localhost:27017. Write error: WriteError{code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: testdb.Van index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('65107022c9933220c3b24f0e') }', details={}}.))

I don't understand why this is coming because dao execution is only once.